# /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available

Tags: software-installation

i have tried to install **Real-time Human Pose Estimation in the Browser with TensorFlow.js** from [this](https://medium.com/tensorflow/real-time-human-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-7dd0bc881cd5) instruction but i have some problem with npm ,i had this output :

```
so@so-notebook:~/Downloads$ npm install  @tensorflow/tfjs-core@^1.3.0
/usr/bin/nodejs: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
/usr/bin/nodejs: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
/usr/bin/nodejs: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
/usr/bin/nodejs: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
/usr/bin/nodejs: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/nodejs)
/home/so/Downloads
└─┬ @tensorflow/tfjs-core@1.7.4 
  ├── @types/offscreencanvas@2019.3.0 
  ├── @types/seedrandom@2.4.27 
  ├── @types/webgl-ext@0.0.30 
  ├── @types/webgl2@0.0.4 
  ├── node-fetch@2.1.2 
  └── seedrandom@2.4.3 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/so/Downloads/package.json'
npm WARN Downloads No description
npm WARN Downloads No repository field.
npm WARN Downloads No README data
npm WARN Downloads No license field.
```

i have tried install **openssl** by this command :

```
so@so-notebook:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install openssl1.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kbuild libgsoap-2.8.60 module-assistant virtualbox-source
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openssl1.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 207 kB of archives.
After this operation, 844 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 openssl1.0 amd64 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3 [207 kB]
Fetched 207 kB in 1s (165 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package openssl1.0.
(Reading database ... 523290 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openssl1.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl1.0 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3) ...
Setting up openssl1.0 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3) ...
```

**Update:**

it is not installed in `/usr/local/` based of [this](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL.md) information:
[image]

because that folder is like this:

[image]
but the warning is not solved!?

```
so@so-notebook:~/Downloads$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
so@so-notebook:~/Downloads$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Thanks.